# Definition of 'Abelian variety has CM by $K$'

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

Let $K$ be a number field, let $L⊆K$ be CM field.
$A/K$ be an Abelian variety over $K$.

$A/K$ is said to have CM by $L$ if there is embedding $L⊆End_K(A) \otimes  \Bbb{Q}$.

But if we adapt this definition, **$L$ need not to be unique**, I think.
But I think it's weird to say if both $L$ and $L⊆L'$ satisfies the condition above, $A/K$ has CM by $L$. How can I eliminate this weirdness and get uniqueness of $L$ ?

Comment: I believe $L$ is supposed to be maximal, but even then I don't see a reason a priori for it to be unique. Does that matter, though?

Comment: Yes, a text I study defines CM variety as above and I think this is weird. I want to adapt definition 'L is maximal CM field such that..', but no book or pdf adapts this definition as long as I know.